# XGBoost training on sample of time series data

Tags: python, time-series, xgboost

I am new to XGBoost and would like to use it on a time series dataset. Here is the scenario I'm faced with:

The data set contains N samples of length T, with N>>T. I'd like to train an XGBoost model to predict the next H values, with H<<T. So the input has shape (N,T) and the labels has shape (N,H). However, it appears that XGBRegressor (see [docs](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html)) requires labels to be shape (N,).

My question: How would one train using all N samples to predict the next H values?

Comment: What data are your working with and what is the concrete prediction task?

Answer (score 1):

More generally seen, your problem is, that you want to predict a **multi-variate / multi-dimensioan lable**, but your algorithm only supports **uni-variate / 1-dimensional target variables**.

I see two direct approaches that you could try:

###### Independent Models

You could train $H$ independent XGBoost Models, one for each target dimension.
sklearn already provides [a wrapper](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor.html) for this:

```
model = MultiOutputRegressor(XGBRegressor())
model.fit(X, y)
```

###### Flatten the output

You could turn each sample into $H$ different samples, one for each output dimension. In order to distinguish these dimensions, you could add the index of the output as another feature.
In other word, your $(N,T)$ input would be transformed into an $(N\cdot H, T+1)$ input and your target into an $(N\cdot H)$ vector.

For example, the data

```
X = [[1, 5, -3], 
     [2, 4, 6]]
y = [[4, 6], 
     [13, 20]]
```

would be transformed into

```
X = [[1, 5, -3, 1], 
     [1, 5, -3, 2], 
     [2, 4, 6, 1],
     [2, 4, 6, 2]]
y = [4, 6,13,20]
```